# Python (exe) - prompt_toolkit.terminal.win32_output.NoConsoleScreenBufferError: No Windows console found. Are you running cmd.exe?

Tags: python-2.7, cmd, pyinstaller, exe

Es la primera vez que utilizo pyInstaller para convertir un script python a exe.

Tengo un script escrito en python que utiliza varias librerias. Entre ellas 'whaaaaat' ( https://github.com/markfink/whaaaaat)

Cuando ejecuto el script en la **cmd** usando el comando `python my-script.py` se ejecuta todo correctamente sin ningún problema.

Luego he querido pasar mi script a exe utilizando pyInstaller, pero al ejecutar el archivo .exe resultante me aparece el siguiente error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "my-script.py", line 896, in <module>
  File "my-script.py", line 170, in menu
  File "site-packages\whaaaaat\prompt.py", line 65, in prompt
  File "site-packages\prompt_toolkit\shortcuts.py", line 576, in run_application
  File "site-packages\prompt_toolkit\shortcuts.py", line 118, in create_output
  File "site-packages\prompt_toolkit\terminal\win32_output.py", line 80, in __init__
  File "site-packages\prompt_toolkit\terminal\win32_output.py", line 172, in get_win32_screen_buffer_info
prompt_toolkit.terminal.win32_output.NoConsoleScreenBufferError: No Windows console found. Are you running cmd.exe?
[7052] Failed to execute script my-script
```

Siempre ejecuto el script desde la cmd.

Tengo Python 2.7 (Y no puedo cambiar de versión)

¿Alguien sabría decirme porque me salta este error?

Gracias! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente he acabado utilizando cx_Freeze para exportar mi archivo .py a .exe y el error ha desaparecido.

:)